# Matlab array that decreases from the center

Tags: arrays, matlab

I've been trying to make a 2-dimensional array that has the largest number in the center, and numbers around it decrement by one like this:

```
[0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
 0  1  1  1  1  1  0;
 0  1  2  2  2  1  0;
 0  1  2  3  2  1  0;
 0  1  2  2  2  1  0;
 0  1  1  1  1  1  0;
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

This is easy using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
M = 7; % desired size. Assumed to be odd
t = [0:(M-1)/2 (M-3)/2:-1:0].';
result = min(t, t.');
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the [`gallery`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html) function with the `'minij'` option to produce one quadrant of the result, and then extend symmetrically:

```
M = 7; % desired size. Assumed to be odd
result = gallery('minij',(M+1)/2)-1;
result = [result result(:,end-1:-1:1)];
result = [result; result(end-1:-1:1,:)];
```

---

Another approach, using [`padarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) from the Image Processing toolbox:

```
result = 0;
for k = 1:(M-1)/2;
    result = padarray(result+1, [1 1]);
end
```